# Macro to select and activate Hyperlink from cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am having trouble getting my VBA code to activate the hyperlink in the cell selected. The hyperlink navigates to another sheet in the same work book and then the code is designed to pick up the data and paste it back in the original sheet.

```vb
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 6
        Cells(i, 3).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
        Range("D7:E7").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Gauge Lab Asset").Select
        Cells(i, 22).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
```

I keep getting a subscript error on the `Selection.Hyperlinks(1)` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid `Select`ing and qualify the worksheet any `Range` or `Cells` is on.

```vb
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to 6
    With Sheets("Gauge Lab Asset")
       .Cells(i, 3).Hyperlinks(1).Follow _
           NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

       ActiveSheet.Range("D7:E7").Copy _
           Destination:=.Cells(i, 22)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: I tried to input the code you have posted, it is still giving me a subscript error on line 4.

Comment: Then one or more of the cells doesn't have a hyperlink.

Comment: Thank you BigBen, you were correct my first cell had headings in them. I altered the code to skip the header . It is working now.